# RegisterUser: CreateUserWizardStep

Tags: asp.net

I am having a trouble when i am using CreateUserWizardStep to register for a new user.

Could anyone help me to solve out this problem.I have tried to change in the web.config for memebership Provider Tag.

```
<requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false">
```

However it is not still working !...i am using the MYSQL database.

> RegisterUser:
>   CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate
>   does not contain an
>   IEditableTextControl with ID Question
>   for the security question, this is
>   required if your membership provider
>   requires a question and answer.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005):
>   RegisterUser:
>   CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate
>   does not contain an
>   IEditableTextControl with ID Question
>   for the security question, this is
>   required if your membership provider
>   requires a question and answer.]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserStepContainer.get_QuestionTextBox()
>   +1448475    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.CreateControlHierarchy()
>   +172    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.CreateChildControls()
>   +137    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.CreateChildControls()
>   +26    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
>   +87    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnInit(EventArgs
>   e) +90
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer) +333
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer) +210
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control
>   namingContainer) +210
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378

The following is my MembershipProvider in the web.config.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with MySQL. Add this to you Register.aspx file. That worked for me!

Code:

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Pregunta de Seguridad:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Question" 
         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="La pregunta de seguridad es requerida." ToolTip="La pregunta de seguridad es requerida." 
         ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Respuesta de Seguridad:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Answer" 
         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="La respuesta de seguridad es requerida." ToolTip="La respuesta de seguridad es requerida." 
         ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check again:

1: Check you have done right adjustments to membership provider in your web.config. If you are not sure please share your membership provider setting from your web.config.

2: If you have more than one in your web.config, make sure your CUW is in fact using the right membership provider. CUW has a MembershipProvider property to use in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you override your merbershipprovide please remember return the RequiresQuestionAndAnswer value from your config by below steps:

```
   public class SQLMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

private bool _requiresQuestionAndAnswer;


public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
{
    get
    {
        return _requiresQuestionAndAnswer;
    }
}


public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
    if (config["requiresQuestionAndAnswer"].ToLower() == "true")
    {
        _requiresQuestionAndAnswer = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _requiresQuestionAndAnswer = false;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the error is pretty clear: have you added a IEditableTextControl with ID Question for the security question?

Comment: thank you. I can solve the problem...the web.config i am using is not compatiable with that one..that is why..after i change in machine.config..i can do..:-)